# Python VLC not always playing video in fullscreen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc

I am writing a video player for a Raspberry Pi using the `python-vlc` library (version 3.0.16129). I am seeing a flaky issue where the player does not always open in fullscreen, maybe 1 in 10 times the video starts in windowed mode, working 9 out of 10 times just fine. Has anyone seen/solved this issue?

```
class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        os.environ["VLC_VERBOSE"] = "-1"
        self._instance: Instance = Instance(["--video-on-top"])
        self._player: MediaPlayer = self._instance.media_player_new()

    def play(video_path: str):
        self._player.set_fullscreen(True)
        self._player.stop() # often need to supersede videos already playing
        self._player.set_media(video_path)
        self._player.play()
```

Comment: .toggle_fullscreen()

Comment: @DontDownvote didn't seem to work

Answer (score -1):

Both functions `set_fullscreen` and `toggle_fullscreen` come with a caveat:

```
def toggle_fullscreen(self):
    '''Toggle fullscreen status on non-embedded video outputs.
    @warning: The same limitations applies to this function
    as to L{set_fullscreen}().
    '''
    return libvlc_toggle_fullscreen(self)


def set_fullscreen(self, b_fullscreen):
    '''Enable or disable fullscreen.
    @warning: With most window managers, only a top-level windows can be in
    full-screen mode. Hence, this function will not operate properly if
    L{set_xwindow}() was used to embed the video in a
    non-top-level window. In that case, the embedding window must be reparented
    to the root window B{before} fullscreen mode is enabled. You will want
    to reparent it back to its normal parent when disabling fullscreen.
    @param b_fullscreen: boolean for fullscreen status.
    '''
    return libvlc_set_fullscreen(self, b_fullscreen)
```

Without knowing exactly how your video player is implemented, perhaps it's related to that.